# Two Android Dependencies have same dependency, and duplicate class Error

Tags: android, gradle, bouncycastle, bitcoinj

[image]

I use `xrpl-core` and `bitcoinj` libs, and both use `bouncycastle` version 1.72.
I got the above error (screenshot) when building my andriod app.
I tried excluding `bcprov` from the package, but it's still not working.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.bitcoinj:bitcoinj-core:0.17-alpha1'
    implementation('org.xrpl:xrpl4j-core:3.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'bcprov-jdk18on', module: 'library'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group should be the dependency path and the module should be the specific part you want to exclude, for example:

```
group: "org.bouncycastle"
module: "bcprov-jdk18on"
```